# React Conditional rendering mapping an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array-map, conditional-rendering

I have reproduced my scenario in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-l6qh5?file=/demo.js)

I have an array of tags of 5 elements

```
const tagsList = ["Covid 19", "Business", "Energy", "Sport", "Politics"];
```

I am mapping for each tag my `Chip` component

```
  {tagsList.map((tag) => (
    <Chip label={tag} />
  ))}
```

I want to say that if the taglist length is bigger than 2 ( which is my case in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-l6qh5?file=/demo.js:513-582) ) to show me the chip with the tags left, which are 3 ( length - 2 ).

How can i make in the same map function? Is there an other way?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking for, but it sounds as though you want just a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) of your array.

Comment: Yes, can you answer with the code, thanks

Comment: When you say "left" you mean how to position them on the screen, or do you mean to show the first 3 elements ?

Comment: To show the first 3 elements and put an extra element with only the number 2 ( which are the tags left )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you don't mind not starting at position 0:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
      {(tagsList.length > 2 ? tagsList.slice(3, 5) : tagsList).map((tag) => (
        <Chip label={tag} />
      ))}
      {tagsList.length > 2 && <Chip label={tagsList.length - 2} /> }
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tagsList.slice(2)` if the list size is greater than 2.

```
export default function OutlinedChips() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const tagsList = ["Covid 19", "Business","Energy", "Sport", "Politics"];

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {(tagsList.length > 2 ? tagsList.slice(2) : tagsList).map((tag) => (
        <Chip label={tag} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-31f2w?file=/demo.js

Comment: Almost perfect thanks, i have just edited tagsList.slice(0, 2) to show the first 2 elements and i need to show a Chip with the number of tags left ( 3 )

Answer (score 1):

You can collect index (position of element in list) in the map function and act according to your needs, if I understand it wright mayby you could do something like this :

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {/* Change to shortTagsList for check the shortest */}
      {tagsList.map((tag, index) => {
        let length = tagsList.length;
        console.log(length);
        return (
          (length > 2 && index > 2 && <Chip label={tag} />) ||
          (length <= 2 && <Chip label={tag} />)
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ol7dx?file=/demo.js)